# Does ever open cover have a non-degenerate subcover?

Tags: general-topology

By this I mean if $\{U_i: i \in I\}$ is a cover of some topological space $X$,is there a subcover $\{U_i: i \in J\}$, where $J \subseteq I$ such that the removal of any element of $J$ results in something which is not a cover?

In case that isn't clear, another way to say it would be does every open cover have a subcover which is minimal wrt inclusion?

Comment: Consider $U_n = (-n,n)$, covering $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Such covers are said to be *irreducible*. As **Daniel Fischer** points out, not all open covers are irreducible. There is a theorem, however, that every point-finite open cover is irreducible. (A family of sets in a space is point-finite if every point of the space lies in at most finitely many of the sets.)